# Delete characters Left of a point - Unix

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, scripting

I have a file where I have lines of text. Each line is separated by a "," at any given spot. What I need to do is to delete any and all special characters (,./()[]{}_-) left of that comma but keep that comma.

I've tried to juggle the whole text at once, but it gets too hectic with what other operations I need to do to the text.

Thanks.

Comment: Every char including the specials or only the specials?

Comment: @pacholik -- Just the special characters, or anything that't not numbers really

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

`sed -r` mean extended regex, `sed -i` mean edit file in place:

```
sed -ri "s/[.\/\[\]\{\}_-]+\,/,/g" your_file
```

You will match all characters like:
`. / [ ] { } _ -` on the left of a `,` multiple time on a line. And delete them